# Do CPU and GPU work *together* for rendering HEVC?

Tags: video, cpu, gpu, rendering, h.265

I have a home theater PC that I built 7 years ago. The CPU is fairly low-end (Intel i3-4360). It only has 2GB system RAM. I recently tried for the first time to play fairly high bitrate (20Mbps) 4k HEVC video. Unsurprisingly, the CPU alone could not handle this.

So, I installed the most powerful silent (passively cooled) GPU that I could find (Geforce 1030). Now the same video file works almost perfectly, but there are still rare occurrences where it drops a few frames or the audio skips. I'm wondering if a CPU upgrade would help. I don't know if the system needs to choose either CPU or GPU for all rendering load (in which case a CPU upgrade would either not help, or would make the GPU upgrade irrelevant), or if the two processors can share the load (in which case a CPU upgrade would help).

O/S is Win10 if it matters.

Comment: The CPU is needed to grab data from the disk or internet or wherever the files are stored and pass the data to the GPU. If you have a slow HDD then it could be that any other program using the disk is causing the CPU to not be able to grab data fast enough. If you have little memory then it could be paging stuff out to disk and slowing it down that way. The GPU will help a lot with video, but the rest of the system matters too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what are your video player and the codec used, we cannot help with your
question. It is also unlikely that we can find out the answer even if we had all
the information.

However, you don't really need us for an answer.
You can run Task Manager, position to the Performance tab, then play the video while
watching how the CPU and GPU are used.

From general knowledge, expect some mixture of the CPU and GPU, since it is the CPU
that reads the video data from the disk and sends it to the GPU. In essence,
the CPU is driving the GPU.

The performance of the play depends on all of your hardware: disk, memory, CPU,
GPU and data bus. The display driver software is also a crucial component.
In most cases, upgrading the CPU alone, without also upgrading the other components,
will have a limited impact (unless the CPU comes up as a major bottleneck
in your tests).

Comment: D'oh... not sure why I didn't try that already. GPU only @ 30% and CPU even lower. So hardware seems more than sufficient, unless it's an I/O issue elsewhere which I doubt for these bitrates. So most likely a software/codec issue or (unlikely) somewhere else in the A/V system.

Comment: Probably the codec. You might look for a better one or a better player. VLC is the best I know.

Comment: This is all in Kodi, using passthrough for the audio, which is usually what glitches (briefly cutting out once every 10 minutes or so).

Comment: I think Kodi uses the system resources, so a better audio codec might help. You could also try the [Kodi 19.x "Matrix" Release Candidate](https://kodi.tv/article/kodi-19x-matrix-release-candidate) or even [Kodi 20.0 alpha](https://www.free-codecs.com/kodi_download.htm). VLC is best as test since it uses its own built-in codecs.